# html title in jquery modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have a problem with the following code:

```
$("#btn" ).on('click', function(e) {

    var dialog = $( ".step" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "<div class='title'><h4>Testing title</h4></div>",
        title_html: true,
        buttons: [ 

            {
                text: "OK",
                "class" : "btn",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                } 
            }
        ]
    });


    dialog.data( "uiDialog" )._title = function(title) {
        title.html( this.options.title );
    };


    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
    $(".ui-front").removeClass("ui-widget-overlay");
    $(".ui-corner-all").removeClass("ui-widget-header");
    $(".ui-corner-all").removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar");
});
```

The first time the user click the #btn button the modal open but the title shows like text: `<div class='title'><h4>Testing title</h4></div>`. After closing the modal and re-opening it the title shows correctly.

Someone know why the first time doesn't work fine?

Comment: seems you are registering the function `dialog.data( "uiDialog" )._title` on click of button so first it only gets registered and gets called for subsequent opens

Comment: do you need a new dialog created each time button is clicked? Or just to open it?

Comment: I didn't get why you didn't set the correct title at title: "<div class='title'><h4>Testing title</h4></div>",

Comment: @charlietfl I just need open it, the body of the modal is always the same.